# My .css file isn't working inside my .html file

Tags: html, css

This is the **.html** code and the now embedded **.css** code. I cant figure out why it's not detecting the **.css** code at all (btw I have my own reason why I am not using an stylesheet)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Minu esimene veebileht </title>
      <style>  
         {
         background-color: darkblue;
         }
         h1 {
         color: white;
         text-align: center;
         }
         p {
         font-family: Tahoma;
         font-size: 19px;
         }     
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>  </p>
   </body>
   <h1> Lemmik mootorrattad </h1>
   <p> <strong> Mootorratas </strong> kõnekeeles ka tsikkel, mototsikkel; van. mototsüklett on liiklusseaduse mõistes külghaagisega e. külgkorviga või külghaagiseta kaherattaline mootorsõiduk, mille sisepõlemismootori töömaht on üle 50 cm³ või valmistajakiirus on üle 45 km/h. </p>
   <h2> <em> Honda </em> mootorrattad </h2>
   <p> Honda mootorratad on ühed parimad </p>
   <p> <a target="_blank" href="http://bikes.honda.ee/"> Klõpsake siin </a>, et minna Honda leheküljele </p>
   <p> <a target="_self" href="https://et.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mootorratas"> Klõpsake siia </a>. See viib teid mootorrataste vikipeedia leheküljele </p>
   <p> Sellel pildil on Honda mootorratas. </p>
   <img src="src="https://www.driverknowledgetests.com/resources/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/hyosung-gtr-motorbike.jpg" "alt =" mootorratas "/>
</html>
```

Comment: just curious on the line (btw!... why I'm not using an stylehsheet), you mean for this demo or in the project? It kinda contridicts the headline a bit.

Comment: Yeah the headline should probably say "styling" instead of ".css file"

Comment: You seem to have missed a selector for your first style.  Also you close your body tag way too early - all your html needs to be inside it  (not just an empty p tag).   Fix those issues and it will probably work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your background color, I've assuming it's for the body, in which case you need to set the code like this:

```
body { background-color: darkblue; }
```

Also make sure you put all your content inside these tags:

```
<body> </body>
```

So your code should look like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Minu esimene veebileht </title>
      <style>  
         body {
         background-color: darkblue;
         }
         h1 {
         color: white;
         text-align: center;
         }
         p {
         font-family: Tahoma;
         font-size: 19px;
         }     
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1> Lemmik mootorrattad </h1>
    <p> <strong> Mootorratas </strong> kõnekeeles ka tsikkel, mototsikkel; van. mototsüklett on liiklusseaduse mõistes külghaagisega e. külgkorviga või külghaagiseta kaherattaline mootorsõiduk, mille sisepõlemismootori töömaht on üle 50 cm³ või valmistajakiirus on üle 45 km/h. </p>
    <h2> <em> Honda </em> mootorrattad </h2>
    <p> Honda mootorratad on ühed parimad </p>
    <p> <a target="_blank" href="http://bikes.honda.ee/"> Klõpsake siin </a>, et minna Honda leheküljele </p>
    <p> <a target="_self" href="https://et.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mootorratas"> Klõpsake siia </a>. See viib teid mootorrataste vikipeedia leheküljele </p>
    <p> Sellel pildil on Honda mootorratas. </p>
    <img src="src="https://www.driverknowledgetests.com/resources/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/hyosung-gtr-motorbike.jpg" "alt =" mootorratas "/>
   </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. this is my first time coding and i had no clue on what was going on.

Comment: @MarkoNaab Not a problem! You'll often find that it's small things that break the code. It helps to get another perspective, or to "rubber duck" (explain the code line by line to a rubber duck, or other inanimate object) because then you can see where you went wrong. Good luck!